# IE 9 File Upload Box Does Not Show When Clicking On 'Upload File' Button On HTTPS Site

Tags: jquery, iis, https, internet-explorer-9, uploadify

I seem to be having an issue with the uploadify button not firing in Internet Explorer 9.  The site I'm trying to get the upoadify plugin working is hosted on HTTPS, which seems to be the problem because when I test locally on my machine on IE 9 the upload dialog box appears and I can select a file to download.

When debugging the issue on the HTTPS site I noticed that uploadify.swf does not even load.  I keep getting an http error of 'Aborted'.  I'm not sure if anyone else has run into this problem but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible explanation and solution: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;272359